# Cloud Pub/Sub Java client API example not working locally

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working through the [Google Cloud Pub/Sub publishing example](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries).

I use the code from the example, with the exception of using my own project ID and my own topic name.

When trying to run the example, I get the following stack trace:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:533)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:90)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
    at app.purephotos.zipper.Application.main(Application.java:87)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1015)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1137)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:957)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:515)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:490)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:507)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:627)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:515)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:686)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:675)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:277)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:541)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    ... 3 more
```

I am using the credentials of the service account. I am certain that credentials are valid, since I've had bad attemps where I've set the path to the credentials incorrectly, and it told me right away that the file with the credentials could not be located.

Comment: It may be transient ... GCP status reports networking issues at the time of the post ... https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/19008

Comment: @Kolban didn't know about the incident, ty for the link. Google Cloud Pub/Sub seems to be working anyway, according to their status page.

Comment: Do you have network elements like firewall?